# Functions that accept functions in F#

Tags: lambda, f#

I would like to make a function that accepts two values and a function. I am having trouble understanding the syntax, so I have made a minimal example:

```
let foo (x : int, y : int, func : int -> int -> int) =
    func(x, y)
```

An intended output:

```
> foo(2, 3, fun x y -> x + y)
5
```

However I get the compilation error:

```
The expression was expected to have type int, but here has type 'a * 'b
```

How should this be written?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should call `func` passing the args like this

```
func x y
```

Using parens like you would in a C type language will create a tuple, which is what `'a * 'b` is.

Also when you declare/call foo you are using tuples too.

You can probably just do this

```
let foo x y f =
    f x y
```

And let type inference figure it out. Putting things in brackets like `(x, y)` is creating tuples, when you don't need to.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do type inference and curried arguments you can do:

```
let foo (x : int) (y : int) (func : int -> int -> int) =
    func x y
```

Using it like `foo 2 3 (fun x y -> x + y)`

If you want to use a tuple you can do:

```
let foo (x, y, func) =
    func x y
```

Then you can use it like in your example: `foo(2, 3, fun x y -> x + y)`

If you want to do type inference and a tuple you can do:

```
let foo ((x, y, func) : (int * int * (int -> int -> int))) =
        func x y
```

and use it like when it was just tupled.